# how Do I Enhace (bold, Underline or Italise) texts in twenty seconds cv

Tags: bold, cv, italic, underline

I am trying to use the twenty-second CV class to create my CV, and I would like to enhance (bolden, underline or italicise) some texts, like **underlining** the places I have worked and **bolding** the key tasks I did and **italicising** their descriptions in the work experience section starting from line 157.

**What I Want**

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{twentysecondcv}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%PROFILE SIDE BAR%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%PERSONAL INFO%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\profilepic{alice.jpeg} %path of profile pic
\cvname{Alice} %your name
\cvjobtitle{Adventurer}%your actual job position
\cvdate{26 November 1865}%date of birth
\cvaddress{United Kingdom}%address
\cvnumberphone{+39 0325658974}%telphone number
\cvmail{alice@wonderland.com}%e-mail
\cvsite{http://en.wikipedia.org}%personal site


\aboutme{

Alice is a sensible prepubescent girl from a wealthy English family who finds herself in a strange world ruled by imagination and fantasy. Alice feels comfortable with her identity and has a strong sense that her environment comprises clear, logical, and consistent rules and features. Alice's familiarity with the world has led one critic to describe her as a "disembodied intellect". Alice displays great curiosity and attempts to fit her diverse experiences into a clear understanding of the world.}%About me section

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%In the skill bar section, each skill must have a value between 0 and 6 (float)%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\skills{{pursuer of rabbits/5},{good manners/4},{outgoing/4.3},{polite/4},{Java/0.01}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%In the skill text section, each skill must have a value between 0 an 6%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\skillstext{{lovely/4},{narcissistic/3}}

\makeprofile
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%END PROFILE SIDE BAR%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%BODY%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%SIMPLE SECTION%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{interests}
The heroine and the dreamer of Wonderland;  Alice is the principal character.

\section{education}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%TWENTY LIST ITEMS%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%    Four arguments: date; title; where; description %%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{twenty}
  \twentyitem
    {since 1865}
    {Ph.D. {\normalfont candidate in Computer Science}}
    {Wonderland}
    {\emph{A Quantified Theory of Social Cohesion.}}
  \twentyitem
    {1863-1865}
    {M.Sc. magna cum laude}
    {Wonderland}
    {Majoring in Computer Science}
  \twentyitem
    {1861-1863}
    {B.Sc. magna cum laude}
    {Wonderland}
    {Majoring in Computer Science}
  \twentyitem
    {1856-1861}
    {High school}
    {Wonderland}
    {Specializing in mathematics and physics.}
\end{twenty}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%TWENTY LIST SHORTITEMS%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Two arguments: date; title/description %%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{publications}

\begin{twentyshort}
  \twentyitemshort
    {1865}
    {Chapter One, Down the Rabbit Hole.}
  \twentyitemshort
    {1865}
    {Chapter Two, The Pool of Tears.}
  \twentyitemshort
    {1865}
    {Chapter Three,  The Caucus Race and a Long Tale.}
  \twentyitemshort
    {1865}
    {Chapter Four,  The Rabbit Sends a Little Bill.}
  \twentyitemshort
    {1865}
    {Chapter Five,  Advice from a Caterpillar.}
\end{twentyshort}



\section{awards}

\begin{twentyshort}
  \twentyitemshort
    {1987}
    {All-Time Best Fantasy Novel.}
  \twentyitemshort
    {1998}
    {All-Time Best Fantasy Novel before 1990.}
\end{twentyshort}


\section{experience}

\begin{twenty}
  \twentyitem
    {1900}
    {Alice in Wonderland-The Circra (1900's) Silent Film.}
    {Film}
    {The first Alice on film was over a hundred years ago.}
  \twentyitem
    {1933}
    {Alice in Wonderland 1933 version.}
    {Film}
    {This film stars Ethel griffies and Charlotte Henry. It was a box office flop when it was released.}
\twentyitem
    {1951}
    {Disney Film.}
    {Film}
    {Walt Disney brings Lewis Carroll's fantasy story to life in this well-done animated classic. Even though many elements from the book were dropped, such as the duchess with the baby pig and mock turtle, this version is without a doubt the most famous Alice adaptation made.}

\end{twenty}
\section{other information}
Alice approaches Wonderland as an anthropologist but maintains a strong sense of noblesse oblige that comes with her class status. She has confidence in her social position, education, and the Victorian virtue of good manners. Alice feels entitlement, particularly when comparing herself to Mabel, whom she declares has a “poky little house,” and no toys. Additionally, she flaunts her limited information base to anyone who will listen and becomes increasingly obsessed with the importance of good manners as she deals with the rude creatures of Wonderland. Alice maintains a superior attitude and behaves with solicitous indulgence toward those she believes are less privileged.

\newpage
\newgeometry{left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.1cm,bottom=0.2cm}
\renewcommand{\twentyitem}[4]{%
  \hspace{5pt}#1&\parbox[t]{18.3cm}{%  <--- This line is the change
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize#3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
 
\section{Working Experience}
\begin{twenty}
\twentyitem
{2023-2023}
{Novartis Holding AG. Postfach Basel, Switzerland}
{Data Analytics Intern}
{Data Cleaning: so so and so.\\ Statistical modelling: Linear Mixed-Effect Models for Natural Progression of Geographic Atrophy Lesion Growth
1. Data Collection: Gathering data from various sources, including clinical trials, research studies, and healthcare databases.
            
            2. Data Cleaning: Preprocessing data to remove inconsistencies, errors, and missing values to ensure accuracy and reliability for analysis.
            
            3. Data Analysis: Supporting data analysis using statistical methods and tools to identify trends, patterns, and insights relevant to drug development, patient outcomes, and market trends.
            
            4. Visualization: Creating visualizations such as charts, graphs, and dashboards to communicate data insights to stakeholders effectively.
            
            5. Machine Learning: Assisting in developing and applying machine learning models to predict outcomes, optimize processes, and enhance decision-making in areas like drug discovery and patient care.
            
            6. Report Writing: Helping prepare reports and presentations summarising findings and recommendations based on data analysis.
            
            7. Collaboration: Working closely with cross-functional teams, including research scientists, clinical experts, and business analysts, to support data-driven projects and initiatives.
            
            8. Research: Conducting literature reviews and staying updated on the latest trends and techniques in data analytics and pharmaceutical research.
            
            9. Data Governance: Supporting efforts to ensure data quality, security, and compliance with regulatory standards and company policies.
            
            10. Continuous Learning: Actively participating in training and development opportunities to enhance data analytics skills and understanding of the pharmaceutical industry.
            
        }
    \end{twenty}
    \begin{twenty}
        \twentyitem
        {2012-2023}
        {National Bureau of Statistics}
        {Senior Statistician}
        {
            1. Data Collection: Designing surveys and experiments to collect data on various economic, social, and environmental indicators.
            
            2. Data Analysis: Analyzing collected data using statistical methods to identify trends, patterns, and relationships.
            
            3. Statistical Modeling: Developing and applying statistical models to forecast future trends and make predictions based on available data.
            
            4. Quality Control: Ensuring the accuracy and reliability of data by implementing quality control measures and validating data sources.
            
            5. Report Writing: Preparing reports and publications that summarize statistical findings and provide insights to policymakers, researchers, and the public.
            
            6. Policy Advice: Providing expert advice to government agencies and policymakers based on statistical analysis to inform decision-making and policy development.
            
            7. Data Dissemination: Managing the dissemination of statistical information through various channels, including websites, press releases, and public presentations.
            
            8. Capacity Building: Training and mentoring junior statisticians and other staff members in statistical methodologies and best practices.
            
            9. Collaboration: Working with other government agencies, international organizations, and research institutions to coordinate data collection efforts and share best practices.
            
            10. Innovation: Exploring new statistical methods, technologies, and data sources to improve the efficiency and effectiveness of statistical operations.            
        }
    \end{twenty}
    \begin{twenty}
        \twentyitem
        {2010-2012}
        {Industrial and General Insurance Plc, Nigeria.}
        {Junior Statistician}
        {
            1. Data Analysis: Assisting in analyzing data related to insurance claims, premiums, and policyholder demographics to identify trends and patterns.
            
            2. Risk Assessment: Supporting the development of models to assess and quantify risks associated with different insurance products and policies.
            
            3. Pricing: Helping in the calculation of premium rates for various insurance products based on statistical analysis of risk factors.
            
            4. Claims Analysis: Assisting in the examination of historical claims data to identify factors that influence the frequency and severity of claims.
            
            5. Reserving: Supporting the estimation of reserves required to cover future claims liabilities based on statistical models.
            
            6. Reporting: Assisting in the preparation of statistical reports and presentations for management, regulators, and other stakeholders.
            
            7. Market Research: Conducting statistical analyses of market trends and customer behavior to inform product development and marketing strategies.
            
            8. Data Management: Assisting in the management and maintenance of databases containing insurance-related data.
            
            9. Regulatory Compliance: Supporting efforts to ensure that the company's statistical practices comply with regulatory requirements and industry standards.
            
            10. Collaboration: Working with other departments, such as underwriting, finance, and claims, to provide statistical insights and support decision-making processes.        
            
        }
    \end{twenty}
    \begin{twenty}
        \twentyitem
        {2009 - 2010}
        {Bank of Agriculture, Nigeria.}
        {Data Entry Officer}
        {
            1. Data Input: Entering and updating customer information, loan applications, and account details into the bank's database accurately and efficiently.
            
            2. Record Maintenance: Maintaining and organizing records of agricultural loans, subsidies, and grants to ensure they are easily accessible for review and analysis.
            
            3. Document Verification: Verifying the accuracy of data provided by customers and other sources, ensuring that all information is complete and correct.
            
            4. Data Quality Control: Performing regular checks to ensure the integrity and quality of data entered into the system, identifying and correcting errors or inconsistencies.
            
            5. Reporting: Generating reports based on the data entered, such as loan disbursement reports, repayment schedules, and customer account summaries.
            
            6. Customer Support: Assisting customers with inquiries related to their accounts or loan applications by retrieving and providing relevant information from the database.
            
            7. Compliance: Ensuring that data entry practices comply with bank policies, as well as legal and regulatory requirements related to data privacy and security.
            
            8. Collaboration: Working closely with other departments, such as loan processing, finance, and customer service, to support the bank's operations and services.
            
            9. Data Backup: Ensuring that all data is backed up regularly to prevent loss of information due to system failures or other unforeseen events.
            
            10. Continuous Improvement: Identifying opportunities to improve data entry processes and systems to enhance efficiency and accuracy.
        }
    \end{twenty}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%ENDBODY%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```